# import csv containing mulitibyte content (Arabic and Japanese ) to mysql tables using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, multibyte

import csv containing multibyte content (Arabic and Japanese ) using php. php's fgetcsv() is not compatible with mulitibyte strings like(Arabic,Korean). Is there any other function/method available in php which will help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried toggling setlocale()? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

This should flip the locale to the appropriate language and read the csv correctly.

(Untested - but that's what it says in the manual!)